# Binary Tree - Complete

Tags: c, binary-search-tree

I am currently learning about the BST and writing different functions such as insert search. I came across an interesting programming interview question and it asked to write a function that will check if the bst is complete.

So my understanding is that a BST is complete if all the leaves terminate at the same level.

My **possible approach** for this solution

I figured that height of the right and left nodes should be the same if the leaves under them terminate at the same level. so can I do a simple check to see if the height of a right sub tree is the same as the left sub-tree and if it is then that should indicate to me that the BST tree is complete. Can anyone confirm if my approach is right or suggest other possible approaches? i am not looking for code just want to work on my understanding and approach.

Comment: Number of nodes = 2^n - 1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your recursive approach is almost correct. What you want to ask about a given node are the following questions:

- Is the left child the root of a complete BST, and if so, what is its height?
- Is the right child the root of a complete BST, and if so, is its height the same as that of the left child?

If the answer to both is yes, you have a complete BST.

A different way to solve this problem is to answer the following three questions about the tree.

- Is it a BST?
- How many nodes are in it?
- What is its height?

If the tree is a BST of height `h` with `2**h - 1` nodes, you have a complete BST. Each of the three questions can be answered with a recursive tree traversal.

Answer (score 1):

Your approach won't work because the tree might be equal on left and right and not the same for all leaves like:

```
      5
      /\
     3  6
    /   \
   1     7
```

This tree has equal left and right but 6 doesn't have left child and 3 doesn't have right child.
And the definition of complete tree is 
A complete binary tree is a binary tree in which every level, except possibly the last, is completely filled, `and all nodes are as far left as possible`

Number of nodes = 2^n-1 is not going to solve it as well because it might contain that number but not balanced.

The correct approach would be to

- traverse the tree using something like post-order traversal and when you reach the first leaf, you set the `max_depth`
- during the traversal if you reach a leaf node, it must be at `max_depth` or depth can decrease to be `max_depth -1` but the depth can't increase again after that.

and that is to handle a case like this (which is a complete BST tree)

```
      4
      /\
     2  6
    / \  /\
   1   3 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your basic idea I think is correct. You just recursively check whether the left tree is of the same height as the right tree.

The code looks like

```
int isComplete(Tree *t){
    if(t->left==NULL && t->right==NULL)
        return 0;
    else if(t->left!=NULL && t->right != NULL){   
        int leftheight = isComplete(t->left);
        int rightheight = isComplete(t->right);
        if(leftheight == rightheight && leftheight != -1)
            return leftheight+1；
    }
    return -1;
}
```

-1 indicates not complete. A non-negative return indicates the height of the tree.